# ServiceStack put Authentication to Razor view

Tags: c#, .net, razor, servicestack

*(I am talking about pure SS project, please not to be confused with MVC Razor)*

How do we limit the visit to a SS Razor view with authentication?

That is, how do we call user session and auth code from SS Razor?

I wish to do something like this:

```
@inherits ViewPage
@Authenticate(RedirectUrl = "/Login")

<div>Hello @UserSession.UserName</div>
<div>You are in the secured area now</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of any method to do this directly from a SS Razor page. However, when I had the same dilemma I solved it by creating a service that served up the page instead. That way you can decorate the page's service with the `Authorize` attribute and it will get redirected to the login page if the user is not authenticated.

```
[Authorize]
public class MyPageService : IService<MyRequestDTO>
{
    public object Execute(MyRequestDTO request)
    {
        ...
        return new MyPageViewModel();
    }
}
```

To retrieve the current session in the razor page you can use `GetSession<T>`.

```
@{
    var currentSession = GetSession<CustomUserSession>();
}

<div>Hello @currentSession.UserName</div>
```

Another advantage of this is that you can get a strongly typed view and provide data for the view from the service.

```
@inherits ViewPage<MyPageViewModel>
```

Comment: Firstly, thanks very much for the reply. When you say "use a service interface" do you mean, make a base class like "AuthenticateService" then "MyService" inherit that. MyService:AuthenticateService, also have AuthenticateResponse:IhasResponseStatus then MyResponse:AuthenticateResponse ... like that?

Comment: @Tom, used bad wording there. What I meant was to create a service. I edited the answer.